# Auto deploy docker containers from registry?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a private Docker container registry, GitHub Packages in my case. Many GitHub repositories upload containers to this container registry. I am searching for a solution that automatically pulls those containers and starts them. At the time I am using a self-written shell script that runs after every container registry push.

All big cloud providers (AWS, Google Cloud, Digital Ocean, ...) have this feature to auto-deploy the repository Docker file. Is there any software that does this, which can be self-hosted?

Unfortunately, tags like docker, CI/CD, and deployment are not available and I cannot create them due to not enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/l723kt/selfhosted_digitalocean_app_platform_alternative/) I have found the solution. It is called [Platform as a service (PaaS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service).

Here are some self-hosted solutions:

- [Dokku](https://dokku.com) (The most famous one; Single host only; Docker and buildpack deployments)
- [CapRover](https://caprover.com) (Web GUI; Supports multiple instances; Docker only; Includes Certificate management)
- [Rancher](https://rancher.com/) (More advanced; Based on Kubernetes)

If you don't want to host it yourself there are providers like:

- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)
- [Digital Ocean App Platform](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/)
- and many more

You can find a detailed PaaS comparison here: https://www.mskog.com/posts/heroku-vs-self-hosted-paas/

I am using CapRover now because it is the best solution for my case.